# How do I retrieve all function calls from C++ source files with libclang?

Tags: python, c++, libclang

I'm learning to parse some C++ source file with `python-libclang`, so far I have a script that can partially achieve what I hope:

```
import clang.cindex

idx = clang.cindex.Index.create()
tu = idx.parse('example.cpp', args='-xc++ --std=c++11'.split())
for cursor in tu.cursor.walk_preorder():
    print("`{}` --> {}".format(cursor.spelling, cursor.kind))
```

This script can parse a `example.cpp`

```
// example.cpp
// I know this is incomplete but this is all I got: some incomplete files
int main()
{
    Thing *thing = new Thing();
    thing->DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

and print out:

```
`example.cpp` --> CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT
`main` --> CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL
`` --> CursorKind.COMPOUND_STMT
`` --> CursorKind.DECL_STMT
`thing` --> CursorKind.VAR_DECL
`` --> CursorKind.RETURN_STMT
`` --> CursorKind.INTEGER_LITERAL
```

Yet there is no information about function `DoSomething()`. How do I locate all function calls (and hopefully their fully-qualified names) from a source file?

E.g. how do I get a `Thing::DoSomething`, or at least a `DoSomething`?

---

I have read and tried examples from

- [How to retrieve class names and its method names from C++ header using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072048/how-to-retrieve-class-names-and-its-method-names-from-c-header-using-python)
- [How can I retrieve fully-qualified function names with libclang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292703/how-can-i-retrieve-fully-qualified-function-names-with-libclang/40328378#40328378)
- https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/examples/cindex/cindex-dump.py
- https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/examples/cindex/cindex-includes.py

but none of them get what I want.

Recommendation to any other **SIMPLE** tools to parse C++ source files is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work as you expect since `Thing` is lacking a definition, or even a declaration. Clang is not parsing this as a function call, since as far as it's concerned, the code is not well formed. To see, try adding a declaration like

```cpp
struct Thing { void DoSomething(); };
```

and you will see your missing function calls appear like:

```
`Thing` --> CursorKind.TYPE_REF
`DoSomething` --> CursorKind.CALL_EXPR
`DoSomething` --> CursorKind.MEMBER_REF_EXPR
```

(tested with LLVM 14)

Comment: This is all I got. I don't have access to the complete code.

Comment: In that case your 'complete code' is not valid in the first place. If you don't even have a function prototype, no compiler would accept the code. There's no way to disambiguate something like `thing->foo()` from an indirect function pointer call, a member method call, or an `operator()` call, so Clang cannot give you an answer. As proof, try including the proposed `struct` in your example code, see that it works, then try replacing it with `struct Thing { std::function<void(void)> DoSomething; }` and note that your output changes as a consequence.