# How to get full name of a type in clang with python?

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

Tried to get full name of the type of member variable or params variable. For example, `private B* b` should give `nm::B*` and `void f(B& var)` should give `void (nm::B&)`

```
namespace nm{
class B;


}
using namespace nm;
class A{
private B* b;
};

void f(B& var);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292703/how-can-i-retrieve-fully-qualified-function-names-with-libclang) is an example to get full name of function, but without variable full name.

Comment: Accessing private members is breaking design, so DO NOT even try it. Also C++ names will be mangled (and be compiler specific), so IMO it is just better to haven an `extern "C"` api hiding all the C++ class and name mangling stuff.  This also makes your interface explicit and will only expose what you really want to be usable from python.

Comment: Have you tried `node.type.get_canonical().spelling`, where `node` is a `clang.cindex.Cursor`?

Comment: @joergbrech `print(node.type.get_canonical().spelling)` did give `nm::B *`! Thank you!

Comment: This is not valid C++. The premise also makes no sense, `f` doesn't have type `nm::B&`.

Comment: @PasserBy Fixed that, it should be `void (nm::B&)`