# How can I get the fully qualified names of return types and argument types using libclang's python bindings?

Tags: python, c++, libclang

Consider the following example. I use `python clang_example.py` to parse the header `my_source.hpp` for function and method declarations.

## my_source.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once 

namespace ns {

    struct Foo {
        struct Bar {};

        Bar fun1(void*);
    };

    using Baz = Foo::Bar;

    void fun2(Foo, Baz const&);
}
```

## clang_example.py

I use the following code to parse the function & method declarations using libclang's python bindings:

```py
import clang.cindex
import typing


def filter_node_list_by_predicate(
    nodes: typing.Iterable[clang.cindex.Cursor], predicate: typing.Callable
) -> typing.Iterable[clang.cindex.Cursor]:

    for i in nodes:
        if predicate(i):
            yield i
        yield from filter_node_list_by_predicate(i.get_children(), predicate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    translation_unit = index.parse('my_source.hpp', args=['-std=c++17'])

    for i in filter_node_list_by_predicate(
        translation_unit.cursor.get_children(), 
        lambda n: n.kind in [clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL, clang.cindex.CursorKind.CXX_METHOD]
    ):
        print(f"Function name: {i.spelling}")
        print(f"\treturn type: \t{i.type.get_result().spelling}")
        for arg in i.get_arguments():
            print(f"\targ: \t{arg.type.spelling}")
```

## Output

```
Function name: fun1
        return type:    Bar
        arg:    void *
Function name: fun2
        return type:    void
        arg:    Foo
        arg:    const Baz &
```

Now I would like to extract the fully qualified name of the return type and argument types so I can correctly reference them from the outermost scope:

```
Function name: ns::Foo::fun1
        return type:    ns::Foo::Bar
        arg:    void *
Function name: ns::fun2
        return type:    void
        arg:    ns::Foo
        arg:    const ns::Baz &
```

Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40328378/12173376) I can get the fully qualified name of the function declaration, but not of the return and argument types.

How do I get the fully qualified name of a type (not a cursor) in clang?

**Note:**

I tried using `Type.get_canonical` and it gets me close:

```py
print(f"\treturn type: \t{i.type.get_result().get_canonical().spelling}")
        for arg in i.get_arguments():
            print(f"\targ: \t{arg.type.get_canonical().spelling}")
```

But `Type.get_canonical` also resolves typedefs and aliases, which I do not want. I want the second argument of `fun2` to be resolved as `const ns::Baz &` and not `const ns::Foo::Bar &`.

**EDIT:**

After having tested [Scott McPeak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77947098/12173376) on my real application case I realized that I need this code to properly resolve template classes and nested types of template classes as well.

Given the above code as well as

```cpp
namespace ns {
   template <typename T>
   struct ATemplate {
      using value_type = T;
   };

   typedef ATemplate<Baz> ABaz;

   ABaz::value_type fun3();
}
```

I would want the return type to be resolved to `ns::ABaz::value_type` and not `ns::ATemplate::value_type` or `ns::ATemplate<ns::Foo::Bar>::value_type`. I would be willing to settle for `ns::ATemplate<Baz>::value_type`.

Also, I can migrate to the C++ API, if the functionality of the Python bindings are too limited for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a simple way to print a
type using fully-qualified names.  Even in the C++ API,
[`QualType::getAsString(PrintingPolicy&)`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html#a91caffdd36202abe63291e68ff746e21)
ignores the
[`SuppressScope`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1PrintingPolicy.html#a725ae414e3de49a91ff55d890fac10f2)
flag due to the intervention of the
[`ElaboratedTypePolicyRAII`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/AST/TypePrinter.cpp#L104)
class (I don't know why, and the git commit history offers no clues
that I could find).  Even if the C++ API worked as I would have
hoped/expected, `PrintingPolicy` isn't exposed in the C or Python APIs.

Consequently, to do this, we have to resort to taking apart the type
structure in the client code, printing fully qualified names whenever
we hit a named type, which is typically expressed as
`TypeKind.ELABORATED`.  (I'm not sure if they always are.)

The following example program demonstrates the technique, embodied by
the `type_str` function.  As a proof of concept, it does not
exhaustively handle all of the cases, although it does cover the most
common ones.  You can look at the source of
[`TypePrinter.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/AST/TypePrinter.cpp)
to get an idea of what handling all cases entails.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Print types with fully-qualified names.

This demonstrates the basic approach, digging into the type structure to
print its details, including fully-qualified names when we encounter
named types.  However, there are several unhandled cases, some of which
are indicated with TODOs below.

Also, beware that I was unable to get 'mypy' to work properly on this
(despite installing the 'types-clang' package), so the type annotations
below might be incorrect.
"""

import clang.cindex
import typing


def get_decl_fqn(decl: clang.cindex.Cursor) -> str:
    """
    Given a Cursor that refers to a Declaration, get its fully
    qualified name.
    """

    # The semantic parent is the enclosing class, namespace, or
    # translation unit.
    parent = decl.semantic_parent
    assert(parent is not None)

    # When we hit the TU, just return the simple identifier.
    if parent.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT:
        return decl.spelling

    # Otherwise, print the parent name as a qualifier.
    else:
        return get_decl_fqn(parent) + "::" + decl.spelling


def starts_with_letter(s: str) -> bool:
    """
    True if 's' starts with a letter.
    """

    return s != "" and s[0].isalpha()


def ends_with_letter(s: str) -> bool:
    """
    True if 's' ends with a letter.
    """

    return s != "" and s[-1].isalpha()


def join_type_strs(s1: str, s2: str) -> str:
    """
    Join two strings containing fragments of type syntax, inserting a
    space if both are non-empty and either has a letter adjacent to the
    joined edge.
    """

    if s1 != "" and s2 != "" and (ends_with_letter(s1) or starts_with_letter(s2)):
        return s1 + " " + s2
    else:
        return s1 + s2


def type_str(t: clang.cindex.Type) -> str:
    """
    Print 't' in C++ syntax, using fully qualified names for named
    types.  (In contrast, 't.spelling' omits qualifiers.)
    """

    return join_type_strs(before_type_str(t), after_type_str(t))


def before_type_str(t: clang.cindex.Type) -> str:
    """
    Print the part of 't' that would go before the declarator name in a
    declaration of a variable with that type.
    """

    return join_type_strs(before_type_str_nq(t), cv_qualifiers_str(t))


def cv_qualifiers_str(t: clang.cindex.Type) -> str:
    """
    If 't' has any const/volatile/restrict qualifiers, return a string
    containing them, separated by spaces.  Otherwise, return "".
    """

    qualifiers = []
    if t.is_const_qualified():
        qualifiers.append("const")
    if t.is_volatile_qualified():
        qualifiers.append("volatile")
    if t.is_restrict_qualified():
        qualifiers.append("restrict")

    return " ".join(qualifiers)


def before_type_str_nq(t: clang.cindex.Type) -> str:
    """
    Print the part of 't' that would go before the declarator name in a
    declaration of a variable with that type, ignoring any CV
    qualifiers.
    """

    if t.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.ELABORATED:
        # Most named types are represented with the "elaborated" node,
        # which typically has a name.
        return get_decl_fqn(t.get_declaration())

    elif t.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.POINTER:
        p = t.get_pointee()

        # TODO: This does not handle pointer-to-function properly, since
        # that requires additional parentheses.
        return join_type_strs(before_type_str(p), "*")

    elif t.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.LVALUEREFERENCE:
        p = t.get_pointee()
        return join_type_strs(before_type_str(p), "&")

    elif t.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.RVALUEREFERENCE:
        p = t.get_pointee()
        return join_type_strs(before_type_str(p), "&&")

    elif t.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.FUNCTIONPROTO:
        rettype = t.get_result()
        return before_type_str(rettype)

    # TODO: FUNCTIONNOPROTO, pointer-to-member, and possibly others.

    else:
        # For other types, just use the spelling as its "before" syntax.
        return t.spelling


def after_type_str(t: clang.cindex.Type) -> str:
    """
    Print the part of 't' that would go after the declarator name in a
    declaration of a variable with that type.
    """

    if t.kind == clang.cindex.TypeKind.FUNCTIONPROTO:
        res = "("
        count = 0
        for argtype in t.argument_types():
            if count > 0:
                res += ", "
            count += 1
            res += type_str(argtype)
        res += ")"
        return res

    # TODO: FUNCTIONNOPROTO and the various array types.

    return ""


# ------------- Original code, edited to call 'type_str' ---------------
def filter_node_list_by_predicate(
    nodes: typing.Iterable[clang.cindex.Cursor], predicate: typing.Callable
) -> typing.Iterable[clang.cindex.Cursor]:

    for i in nodes:
        if predicate(i):
            yield i
        yield from filter_node_list_by_predicate(i.get_children(), predicate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    translation_unit = index.parse('my_source.hpp', args=['-std=c++17'])

    for i in filter_node_list_by_predicate(
        translation_unit.cursor.get_children(),
        lambda n: n.kind in [clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL, clang.cindex.CursorKind.CXX_METHOD]
    ):
        print(f"Function name: {i.spelling}")

        # ---- Edited section ----
        # Compare the 'spelling' method to 'type_str' defined above.
        t = i.type
        print(f"\tFunction type spelling  : {t.spelling}")
        print(f"\tFunction type type_str(): {type_str(t)}")


# EOF
```

On your example input, it prints:

```plaintext
$ ./fq-type-name.py
Function name: fun1
        Function type spelling  : Bar (void *)
        Function type type_str(): ns::Foo::Bar (void *)
Function name: fun2
        Function type spelling  : void (Foo, const Baz &)
        Function type type_str(): void (ns::Foo, ns::Baz const &)
```

Notably, this fully qualifies `ns::Foo::Bar` in the return type of
`fun1`.  It also uses `ns::Baz` in the argument list of `fun2`, rather
than using the underlying type, `Bar`.

---

The revised question asks about a case involving templates and a
`typedef` that is used as a scope qualifier, and wants to recover a
fully-qualified name that uses that `typedef`.  This is not possible
using the approach outlined above because we construct the qualifiers
by walking up the scope stack from the found declaration, ignoring how
the type was expressed originally.

Using the Python API, it is possible to see the original type syntax and
its qualifiers by iterating over children, but the child list is
difficult to interpret.  For example, if the input is:

```
namespace ns {
  struct A {
    struct Inner {};
  };
  typedef A B;
  B::Inner f(int x, A a);
}
```

and we use this code to print the TU:

```
def print_ast(node: clang.cindex.Cursor, label: str, indentLevel: int) -> None:
    """
    Recursively print the subtree rooted at 'node'.
    """

    indent = "  " * indentLevel
    print(f"{indent}{label}: kind={node.kind} " +
          f"spelling='{node.spelling}' " +
          f"loc={node.location.line}:{node.location.column}")
    indentLevel += 1

    index = 0
    for c in node.get_children():
        print_ast(c, f"child {index}", indentLevel)
        index += 1
```

then the output is:

```
TU: kind=CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT spelling='test3.cc' loc=0:0
  child 0: kind=CursorKind.NAMESPACE spelling='ns' loc=1:11
    child 0: kind=CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL spelling='A' loc=2:10
      child 0: kind=CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL spelling='Inner' loc=3:12
    child 1: kind=CursorKind.TYPEDEF_DECL spelling='B' loc=5:13
      child 0: kind=CursorKind.TYPE_REF spelling='struct ns::A' loc=5:11
    child 2: kind=CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL spelling='f' loc=6:12
      child 0: kind=CursorKind.TYPE_REF spelling='ns::B' loc=6:3
      child 1: kind=CursorKind.TYPE_REF spelling='struct ns::A::Inner' loc=6:6
      child 2: kind=CursorKind.PARM_DECL spelling='x' loc=6:18
      child 3: kind=CursorKind.PARM_DECL spelling='a' loc=6:23
        child 0: kind=CursorKind.TYPE_REF spelling='struct ns::A' loc=6:21
```

Observe that the qualified type `B::Inner` is expressed as this pair of
adjacent children:

```
      child 0: kind=CursorKind.TYPE_REF spelling='ns::B' loc=6:3
      child 1: kind=CursorKind.TYPE_REF spelling='struct ns::A::Inner' loc=6:6
```

There's no simple way to see that the first child is the qualifier
portion of the second child.  This is a general problem with the Clang C
API, and consequently of the Python API: accessors for specific roles
are often missing, so one must resort to iterating over children and
trying to reverse-engineer which is which.  (I spent a couple weeks
going down this road for a different project, and eventually had to
admit defeat.)

Therefore, with the revised requirement of not merely computing a type
syntax string that uses fully-qualified names, but one that adheres to
the original syntax as closely as possible, I think it's going to be a
difficult task to robustly complete using the Python API since that
original syntax is tough to unambiguously retrieve.

I recommend instead using the C++ API.  This is still non-trivial, but
all the information is there and available through accessors that
distinguish the various "child" roles.  If you want a tip on getting
started, I have a tool on GitHub called
[`print-clang-ast`](https://github.com/smcpeak/print-clang-ast/) that
prints a lot (but by no means all) of the Clang AST in a moderately
readable JSON format.  I even just
[added](https://github.com/smcpeak/print-clang-ast/commit/ab58d561f6672602ddfdc5638a293b0cad553591)
code to print the details of
[`NestedNameSpecifier`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1NestedNameSpecifier.html)
(which is how qualified names are represented) while trying to see if
the Python API could be used for what you what.  If you try to
accomplish this using the C++ API but run into trouble, you could then
ask a new question based on where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the very excellent answer! It is a bit surprising that querying fully qualified names is such a hard task. Note that for my use case I had to add a few lines to `before_type_str_nq` so that the code works for template classes as well (I didn't put that requirement into the question, though).

Comment: Oh, actually this still fails for nested types of class templates, e.g. `std::vector<int>::value_type` will be resolved to `std::vector::value_type` because `get_decl_fqn` is passed the declaration of the `value_type`, which is within the template declaration...

Comment: Thanks for the revised answer. I accept since I cannot ask for more, you have been very helpful. For some context: Adhering to the original syntax as much as possible is not just a question of style: In my case type aliases are different on different platforms and I am trying to generate portable code, i.e. code generated on one platform should be compilable on another.